# Does DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH blocks INSERTS and UPDATES at the tables used at the MV while executing?

Tags: transactions, oracle10g, database, materialized-views

I thik the question is quite clear, but still heres an example:

Let's say i have an MV called "MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW" created using

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW PARALLEL PARTITION BY RANGE (some_date)
    (
      PARTITION RESULT_MATRIX_V_2012 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/01/2013','dd/MM/yyyy')),
      PARTITION RESULT_MATRIX_V_2013 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/01/2014','dd/MM/yyyy')),
      PARTITION RESULT_MATRIX_V_2017 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    )
    NOCOMPRESS
    LOGGING
    BUILD DEFERRED
    USING INDEX TABLESPACE XXISLT_INDEX
    REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
    USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
    DISABLE QUERY REWRITE AS
 SELECT c1,c2
 FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

Then i execute

```
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW','C');
```

And now let's say the last instruction takes about 4 hours to finish and before that happens i try to do this

```
update SOME_TABLE SET c1 = 4 where c2 = 6;
```

What would happen? SOME_TABLE gets blocked?
my doubt is because i didnt found any clear documentation,

Greetings,

Answer (score 0):

The update would succeed.

A materialized view refresh is just like any other reader process.  No process that is reading from a table will block any other session from reading the data in that table.  And just like any other reader, the materialized view will see the data as it existed when the insert operation started.  The materialized view, in other words, would reflect the data as it was prior to the update.

Of course, if you actually created the materialized view that you described, you wouldn't need to call `dbms_mview.refresh` since it was set to commit on refresh.  It also wouldn't generally make much sense to do a complete refresh on such a materialized view since you could do an incremental refresh.  And if you were able to create the materialized view, that would imply that you have a materialized view log on `some_table` in which case the refresh process would generally be using the data in the materialized view log not the data in the table.

Comment: can you please add some references?? the fact is that i actually did the test and until the refresh finished the tables used at the MV got blocked (the tests which lasted more than the configured timeout _timedout_)

and btw, the refresh is needed because i use BUILD DEFERRED